# I am using \if condition in a custom command in my LaTeX document. can i know how to do the if statement in the uploaded image

Tags: ifthenelse

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}% requires a Unicode capable editor
\sisetup{
   detect-mode,
   detect-family,
   detect-inline-family=math,}



\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{PPO} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \For {$i=1,2,\ldots ,m$}
        \EndFor
        
            \For {$i=1,2,\ldots,m$}
            \State $forbidden\_set\leftarrow\theta$
            \State ${u}\leftarrow\ {p}[i]$
            \State ${v\leftarrow\ {get}\_original\_node(u)}$
            \For {each node $s$ that adjacent to $u$}
            \IF{$c[$s$]!\= -1$} 
                \State ${v\leftarrow\ {get}\_original\_node(s)}$
                \State ${a\leftarrow\ Max}\rbra\_original\_node(u)}$
                \ENDIF  
            
                \State Run policy $\pi_{\theta_{old}}$ in environment for $T$ time steps
                \State Compute advantage estimates $\hat{A}_{1},\ldots,\hat{A}_{T}$
            \EndFor
            \State Optimize surrogate $L$ wrt. $\theta$, with $K$ epochs and minibatch size $M\leq NT$
            \State $\theta_{old}\leftarrow\theta$
        
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not load `algorithmic` along `algpseudocode`: they are incompatible with each other.

You're using the former package's syntax, so stick with it and use `\If{...}...\EndIf`.

I also made several changes to the code, please check them carefully. I removed `\rbra` that doesn't appear anywhere; fix it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{algorithmic} %%%% NOT along algpseudocode
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}% requires a Unicode capable editor
\sisetup{
   detect-mode,
   detect-family,
   detect-inline-family=math,}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{PPO} 

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \For {$i=1,2,\dots ,m$}
  \EndFor
  \For {$i=1,2,\dots,m$}
    \State $\mathit{forbidden\_set}\leftarrow\theta$
    \State $u\leftarrow {p}[i]$
    \State $v\leftarrow \mathit{get\_original\_node}(u)$
    \For {each node $s$ that adjacent to $u$}
      \If{$c[s]\neq -1$} 
        \State $v\leftarrow \mathit{get\_original\_node}(s)$
        \State $a\leftarrow \mathit{Max\_original\_node}(u)$
      \EndIf
      \State Run policy $\pi_{\theta_{\mathrm{old}}}$ in environment for $T$ time steps
      \State Compute advantage estimates $\hat{A}_{1},\dots,\hat{A}_{T}$
    \EndFor
    \State Optimize surrogate $L$ wrt. $\theta$, with $K$ 
           epochs and minibatch  size $M\leq\nobreak NT$
    \State $\theta_{\mathrm{old}}\leftarrow\theta$
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic} 

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to fix the long line 15, you could do (wait till you're sure that the text is in final form)

```
    \State Optimize surrogate $L$ wrt. $\theta$, with $K$\hspace*{\fill}\linebreak
           \hspace*{3em}epochs and minibatch  size $M\leq NT$
```

This would yield

[image]